# Python Flask render response body from String instead of template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I know that you can render a view from a template file in Flask.

```
rendered = render_template('pdf/template.html', toPerson=message.to_user, fromPerson=message.from_user, message=message.user_message)
```

I'm wondering how you would render from a string instead of providing the `'pdf/template.html'` section.

I've tried the below but with no luck.

```
loader = DictLoader({
            'template': Template(template_string),
        })
env = Environment(loader=loader)
response = env.get_template('template').render(toPerson="The to person", fromPerson="The from person", message="Lorem Ipsum")
```

I'm getting an error message

> TypeError: Can't compile non template nodes

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a string as a template instead of a loaded file, you can use the [`from_string`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#jinja2.Environment.from_string) function of the existing Jinja environment.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    templ_str = '''<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>'''
    templ = app.jinja_env.from_string(templ_str)
    return templ.render(name='John Doe')
```